# Can I interact with Camtasia's player using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, camtasia

I have a site where i'm showing 2 "tutorial" videos recorded with Camtasia.
They are both "autostart=false"

I'm using the combination of an mp4 file, and the movie_controller.swf files.

I would like to be able to start a movie through Javascript (i'm assuming this is possible), and also get notified in Javascript when the movie finishes.

Is this possible?
Is it documented anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to document my findings, in case someone else needs to do this...

No, you can't.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but:
http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=start+a+movie+through+Javascript

http://www.swishtalk.com/showthread.php?p=9678

http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashGetObject/

Comment: That doesn't really work.
I'm not trying to get a generic Flash animation to play/stop

This is a movie that loads another movie inside of it, and it has a Play button in it.
The question is whether they put an API for me to "click" that button through Javascript